# Masking a shape out of symbol in Sketch 3

Tags: shapes, sketch-app, mask, symbols

I am trying to mask a shape from a symbol in Sketch. In Illustrator I would just use an inverse clipping mask but Sketch doesn't seem to have that option.
[image: Logo]

I am trying to subtract the square from the center of the drop shape but so far have only been able to do the opposite.
[image]
Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here is a tutorial I just created for you. I made it step by step since I didn't know how comfortable you feel with Sketch.

See that the important part is how you create your initial logo. Always on mind that eventually you need to create the same shape than the logo but as a flat-single shape.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to make the initial logo as a symbol, but it would work the same. The only additional step is once you duplicate your symbol to create the mask, you just need to detach it from symbol.

The mask still will work over the symbol underneath

Comment: Zach, you are welcome. After posting this, I kept thinking an came up with a way to make it simpler, but I will leave that for you to investigate :)